# Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: cauchy-sequences, p-adic-number-theory

Let $\left\{a_i\right\},\left\{b_i\right\}$ be two Cauchy sequences with respect to norm $|\cdot |_p$ on $\mathbb{Q},$ that is, $a_i,b_i\in \mathbb{Q},$ and
$$\forall \ \varepsilon>0,\exists N\in \mathbb{N},s.t. n,m> N\Longrightarrow |a_m-a_n|_p<\varepsilon,\ |b_m-b_n|_p<\varepsilon.$$(p is a prime number.)
Such two sequences $\left\{a_i\right\},\left\{b_i\right\}$ are equivalent iff $|a_i-b_i|_p\rightarrow 0.$ $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is the set of  equivalence classes of such Cauchy sequences. For any equivalence class $a\in\mathbb{Q}_p,$ if $\left\{a_i\right\}\in a,$  then the norm of $a$ is defined as$$|a|_p:=\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} |a_i|_p.$$

**Question:** Let $\beta_n (n\in \mathbb{N})$ be a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{Q}_p,$ with respect to norm $|\cdot |_p$ on $\mathbb{Q}_p.$ My textbook says that if $\left\{a_{n_i}\right\}_{i\in \mathbb{N}}\in \beta_n,$ then the equivalence class of the sequence $\left\{a_{i_i}\right\}_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ is the limit of $\beta_n,$ which means, if $\left\{a_{i_i}\right\}_{i\in \mathbb{N}}\in c,$ then $\displaystyle\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} |\beta_i-c|_p=0.$ But I cannot think of a proof. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This text may be useful for you:
http://www.math.columbia.edu/~nironi/completion.pdf

Comment: No matter what notation your text used, it is an Unfriendly Act to use both $a$ and $\alpha$ close together. An Aged Mathematician has lodged this complaint.

Comment: A young mathematician agrees with the aged, @Lubin.

Comment: Does $a_{ni}$ have $n$ in common with $\beta_n$? If so, what does the $n$ in $\beta_n$ represent? Is it the $n^{th}$ element in the sequence $\beta$ or are there many sequences $\beta$ and $n$ identifies them?

Comment: And sorry, I'm confused by the difference between $\beta_n$ and $\{\beta_n\}$. If without the brackets it is perhaps an element within, but it then has further elements within so are we describing any number in $\mathbb Q_2$ as a set which contains the elements in the Cauchy sequence which converges to it?

Comment: The idea is really to mimic the construction of $\mathbb{R}$ as the limits of cauchy sequences of rationals. The other idea is to consider $\mathbb{Z}_p$ as the set of sequences $a_n \in \mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z}, a_n \equiv a_m \bmod p^m, m \le n$ with the pointwise addition and multiplication.

Comment: @reuns yes, and in this notation is a p adic number being described as a set containing the elements in the Cauchy sequence which converges to it?

Comment: @Robert Frost: I just wanted to describe a sequence.... The notation just represents the "concept" of a sequence of things.

Comment: You can also understand it as an ordered countable set, of course.

Comment: And the Cauchy sequences which have the same "limit" or "end" would be viewd as a whole, that is, a p-adic number.

Comment: @painday I'm learning myself.

Comment: @painday and $ii=i^2$?

Comment: @painday the other thing confusing me is you have 'is an element of' stating a set is an element of a Cauchy sequence So I'm trying to translate the Cauchy sequence into an equivalence class of sets to understand what sets it contains. Did you mean subset?

Comment: @Robert Frost: That is double subscript, I'll edit it.

Comment: The point is each $\beta_n$ is a p-adic number, that is, an equivalence class of some Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb{Q}$ which have the same "end".

Comment: And for each $n,$  ${\left\{{a}_{n_i}\right\}}_{\mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence in$\mathbb{Q}.$

Comment: @painday that changes everything!